# One button to open and close div

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I'm trying to use only one button to open and close a div element with ID = "sbMenu"

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="open" OnClick="openSide_Click" class="openbtn fa fa-bars" "></asp:LinkButton>
```

```
 Protected Sub openSide_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        
        'If (sbMenu.Style("width") = "200px") Then
        '    sbMenu.Style.Add("width", "0px")

        'ElseIf (sbMenu.Style("width") = "0px") Then
        '    sbMenu.Style.Add("width", "200px")
        'End If

        'below works but it can only open
        sbMenu.Style.Add("width", "200px")
        contentform.Style.Add("margin-left", "200px")

    End Sub
```

I tried to use the if statement and it doesn't work.
I'm hoping to use only codebehind because this is in the master page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Although that is possible (doing code acrobats) is not the easiest and valid way.
For operations like as you want to do you must use javascript + css.

Comment: Nope, to hide or show an element on postback, you don't set width to zero or mess with the styles. Just change visible property of the server side object.

Comment: I tried using JS and CSS but the div didn't stay open

Comment: @MariniMK try this `sbMenu.Visible = Not sbMenu.Visible`

Answer (score 0):

```
**Javascript**

 function toggleNav() 
   {
        var el = document.getElementById("sbMenu");
        if(el.style.width == "200px"){
            el.style.width = "0px";
        } else {
            el.style.width = "200px";
        }
    }     
    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="open" OnClientClick="toggleNav()"></asp:LinkButton>
```